# How can I print solana error log messages in rust?

Tags: anchor, rust, debug

I am able to see my custom error messages (defined on chain) when I call the [anchor] program using javascript client `node client.js`:

```
error: {
    errorCode: { code: 'MEOW', number: 6003 },
    errorMessage: 'This account a custom err message that I have written',
    comparedValues: undefined,
    origin: { file: 'programs/helloworld/src/lib.rs', line: 46 }
  },
```

the errorCode and errorMessage are especially helpful. How can I print those fields using Rust? Right now, I am only getting

```
Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1774 [5 log messages]

Caused by:
    0: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1774 [5 log messages]
    1: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1774 [5 log messages]
```

my rust client code follows this template:

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    call_instruction()?,
    Ok(())
}

fn call_instruction() -> Result <()> {
    let program = ...;

    let signature = program
    .request()
    .accounts(program::accounts::Test {
        user: program.payer(),
    }).args(program::instruction::Testing {}).send()?;

    println!("Transaction signature: {:?}",signature);
    Ok(())
}
```

In terminal, I have tried setting env variable `RUSTLOG=solana_client=debug` before running `cargo run`, but nothing happens :(

Comment: please update the question to provide the code you're using to print the errors

Comment: I have included the rust client (shortened for readability). I run it with `cargo run`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to print in the context of a test, you might do something like:

```
#[test]
fn some_test() {
 let result = call_instruction();
 if result.is_err(){
  //whatever
 }
}
```

And here you could extract the error (`result.err()`) if you wanted to print the log or code.

More commonly you have some errorCode values specified in your errors.rs, you are emitting these with `return err!(ErrorCode::Whatever);` when something goes wrong, and this gets caught and printed by the caller.

Comment: Hi! yes, my on chain code looks like `return err!(MyError::CustomErrorName);`, but I am not sure what you mean by "gets caught and printed by the caller." :( my terminal prints the "CustomErrorName" when I am using javascript, but for Rust, I can only see `Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1772 [5 log messages]`

Answer (score 0):

RpcClient is returning an error type of "solana_rpc_client_api::client_error::Error".  This Error type contains a member field called "kind" that can be matched against.  For example, to map this to anyhow::Error:

```
    use solana_rpc_client_api::client_error::ErrorKind;
    // ...
    rpc_client
      .send_and_confirm_transaction_with_spinner(&transaction)
      .await.map_err(|e| {
        match e.kind {
        ErrorKind::RpcError(rpc_err) => {
          println!("ERROR: {rpc_err:?}");
          Error::new(rpc_err)
        }
          // match other types
          _ => { Error::new(e) }
        }
    })
```

More specifically, the log messages you are looking for are likely buried down under:
ErrorKind/RpcError/RpcResponseError/RpcResponseErrorData/SendTransactionPreflightFailure/RpcSimulateTransactionResult/logs.